# How do I delete a public store in Exchange 2003?

Tags: exchange-2003

We were looking at a possible way to organize public folders and created a public store for a specific segment of our organization.  It turns out that the idea did not work the way we wanted it to so now we are trying to clean up.

We've removed the folders that were created in it and now we're trying to delete the store.  Each time we do the following message:

```
You cannot delete this public folder store because it contains folder
replicas.  To avoid data loss, right click the public folder store and
use Move All Replicas to move the replicas to a different server.  It
may take several hours until the content is replicated to the new server
and the local replicas are removed.
```

We only have one Exchange server in our organization so there is no way to do what is requested.  How can this store be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [This link](http://msexchangetips.blogspot.com/2006/07/exchange-cannot-delete-public-folder.html)

It describes using the ADSIEDIT tool to do what you need.

EDIT: Be careful, this is a very powerful snap-in!